# Android Kitkat external SD workaround with Mediascanner

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-sdcard, android-4.4-kitkat

Google has restricted write permission for apps to write on  external sd card. One way around this is root ( not a solution for normal customers), but the other, according to AndroidPolice and total commander, is [mediascanner](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=34834&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15):

Here is the workaround class from the link above:

```
import java.io.OutputStream; 

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.content.ContentResolver; 
import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.provider.MediaStore; 

   public class MediaFileFunctions { 
       @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" }) 
       private static Uri getFileUri(Context context,String fullname) { 
          // Note: check outside this class whether the OS version is >= 11 
          Uri uri=null; 
          Cursor cursor=null; 
          ContentResolver contentResolver=null; 
          try{ 
             contentResolver=context.getContentResolver(); 
             if (contentResolver==null) 
                return null; 
             uri=MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"); 
             String[] projection=new String[2]; 
             projection[0]="_id"; 
             projection[1]="_data"; 
             String selection="_data = ? ";    // this avoids SQL injection 
             String[] selectionParams=new String[1]; 
             selectionParams[0]=fullname; 
             String sortOrder="_id"; 
             cursor=contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionParams, sortOrder); 
             if (cursor!=null) { 
                try { 
                   if (cursor.getCount()>0) {  // file present! 
                      cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                      int dataColumn=cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"); 
                      String s=cursor.getString(dataColumn); 
                      if (!s.equals(fullname)) 
                         return null; 
                      int idColumn=cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"); 
                      long id=cursor.getLong(idColumn); 
                      uri=MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external",id); 
                   } else {  // file isn't in the media database! 
                      ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues(); 
                      contentValues.put("_data",fullname); 
                      uri=MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"); 
                      uri=contentResolver.insert(uri,contentValues); 
                   } 
                } catch (Throwable e) { 
                   uri=null; 
                } 
                cursor.close(); 
             } 
          } catch (Throwable e) { 
             uri=null; 
          } 
          return uri; 
       } 

       public static OutputStream getOutputStreamViaContentProvider(Context context,String fullname) { 
          Uri uri=getFileUri(context,fullname); 
          if (uri==null) 
             return null; 
          try { 
             ContentResolver resolver=context.getContentResolver(); 
             return resolver.openOutputStream(uri); 
          } catch (Throwable e) { 
             return null; 
          } 
       } 

       public static boolean deleteViaContentProvider(Context context,String fullname) { 
          Uri uri=getFileUri(context,fullname); 
          if (uri==null) 
             return false; 
          try { 
             ContentResolver resolver=context.getContentResolver(); 
             // change type to image, otherwise nothing will be deleted 
             ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues(); 
             int media_type=1; 
             contentValues.put("media_type", media_type); 
             resolver.update(uri,contentValues,null,null); 
             return resolver.delete(uri,null,null)>0; 
          } catch (Throwable e) { 
             return false; 
          } 
       } 

       public static boolean mkDirViaContentProvider(Context context,String fullname) { 
          String fileName; 
          Uri uri; 
          ContentResolver resolver; 
          try { 
             resolver=context.getContentResolver(); 
             fileName = strcatslash(fullname)+"ghisler_temp.jpg"; 
             ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues(); 
             contentValues.put("_data", fileName); 
             uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues); 
          } catch (Throwable e) { 
             return false; 
          } 
          if (uri!=null) { 
             try { 
                resolver.delete(uri,null,null); 
             } catch (Throwable e) { 
             } 
             return true; 
          } else 
             return false; 
       } 

       public static String strcatslash(String dir) { 
       if (dir.length()>0 && !dir.endsWith("/")) 
          return dir+"/"; 
       else 
          return dir; 
        } 

    }
```

So, in my app, I used this code, now I want to save a bitmap to the extsd location:

```
boolean ok=true; 
FileOutputStream g = null; 
try { 
    g = new FileOutputStream(file); 
} catch (Exception e1) { 
    ok = false; 
} 
if (!ok) { 
    g=(FileOutputStream) MediaFileFunctions.getOutputStreamViaContentProvider(
            mContext,file.toString()); 
    image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, g);
    try {
        g.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        g.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here, "image" is the bitmap containing the image, and file is the file path. After running, a blank picture is saved to sd card.

Any workarounds to this nasty kitkat bug?

Comment: What is the type of file? What does file.toString() deliver? Is it really a fullpath? You are not checking if g=(FileOut.... is maybe null.

Comment: The author of Total Commander does not give a full working example of writing to a file on the sdcard. He only gives an example to let the mediaschanner deliver an InputStream to you. At that moment the file is created but still 0 bytes. Then you try to write bytes to that stream. I think it fails because the stream does not belong to you so you cannot use it. Ask the author if he ever could in this way. Think you should let the resolver write to that stream.

Comment: file.toString() is a valid file path. Also, I had mailed the author, who told me that this process works only on Samsung phones except the S5. But, since a file is actually created (although empty), there MUST be a workaround to flush the bitmap to the stream, I just don't have the required amount of inside knowledge.

Comment: By the workaround author, several months after: (Aug 26, 2014) <<Unfortunately it does not work any more on newer versions of Kitkat, it has all been locked down.>>

Comment: @Avijit did you find the solution?